# Generic Method - Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to T

Tags: c#, generics, interface

May be a simple question..

I have an interface:

```
public interface ISanitizer
{
    T Sanitize<T>(T data_);
}
```

And an implementing class:

```
    public class BasicFilenameSanitizer : ISanitizer
    {

        private readonly String m_replacementCharacter = String.Empty;

        public BasicFilenameSanitizer(String replacementCharacter_)
        {
            if (replacementCharacter_ == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("replacementCharacter_");
            }

            m_replacementCharacter = replacementCharacter_;
        }


        public virtual T Sanitize<T>(T filename_)
        {
            if (filename_ == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("filename_");
            }

            Regex invalidCharacterRegex =
                new Regex(String.Format("[{0}]", Regex.Escape(new string(System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()))));

//error occurs here
            return Regex.Replace(filename_.ToString(), invalidCharacterRegex.ToString(), m_replacementCharacter);
        }

}
```

Comment: The question is so simple, it doesn't exist. Very Zen. At least tell us where the error occurs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code you are returning a `string` from a generic type which could be *anything*.

Change your code to this if you want a *generic* return type:

```
public interface ISanitizer<T>
{
    T Sanitize(T data_);
}

public class BasicFilenameSanitizer : ISanitizer<string>
```

If you simply want to always return a `string` you only need to change the method return type:

```
public interface ISanitizer
{
    string Sanitize<T>(T data_);
}

public virtual string Sanitize<T>(T filename_)
```

Comment: @Ani - if the generic type param shouldn't exist on the interface, then any implementer must create a sanitizer that can accept any `T`, which I'd expect would make implementation difficult. I'd have guessed (as Oded did) that they're missing this parameter on the interface declaration.

Comment: Thanks for this, i went with keeping my interface completely generic.

Answer (score 18):

In my particular case the following code generated the same error:

```
return (T) someData;
```

What helped me out - double cast with object:

E.g:

```
    static T MyFunction<T>() {
        string s = "test";

        if (typeof(T) == typeof(byte[]))
            return (T)(object)System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
            return (T)(object)s;
        else throw new Exception();
    }
```

...

```
            var ba = MyFunction<byte[]>();
            var bs = MyFunction<string>();
```

Comment: the intermediate cast to object then to my generic T type is what did it for me:  `(T)(object)(s)`.  Thanks!

Comment: I lost count of how many times I forgot the intermediate (object) step and got stuck...

Answer (score 0):

Adam,

your interface is incorrect, try:

```
public interface ISanitizer<T, TA>
{
    T Sanitize(TA data);
}

public class BasicFilenameSanitizer<T, TA> : ISanitizer<T, TA>
{
    public virtual T Sanitize(TA data)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Test : BasicFilenameSanitizer<int, string>
{
    public override int Sanitize(string data)
    {
        return data.Length;
    }
    // a little test func...
    public void TestFunc()
    {
        int result = this.Sanitize("fred");
        Console.Write(result);
    }
}
```

**[edited]** - to add example..
cheers..

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the method `Sanitize<T> has`T`as the return type, but the method actually returns a`string`from`Regex.Replace`.

Try changing the method to return a `string` instead:

```
public virtual string Sanitize<T>(T filename_)
```

That means you need to change your method in the interface to return `string` as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
string result = "test";
return (T)Convert.ChangeType(result, typeof(T));
```